# Realizar acción según Ítem en una ListView

Tags: android

Quiero realizar una acción diferente segun el item seleccionado en mi `ListView`,por ejemplo, en un item abrir una pag. web, en otro un activity, pero no eh encontrado el metodo para que lo haga según el item específico.

acá el código:

```
public class ListView extends AppCompatActivity {


String datos[] = {"Ir a Pag. web","Noticias","Informacion","Contacto"};
android.widget.ListView lista;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_view);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    lista = (android.widget.ListView)findViewById(R.id.Mi_Lista); //Inicializo lista
    // preguntar xq funciona con widget y no solo ListView

    final ArrayAdapter<String> adap = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,datos);
    //ArrayAdapter crea las vistas del ListView a partir de los datos almacenados en un array.
    lista.setAdapter(adap);
    //Proporcionar el puntero a la vista de la lista.

    lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override//
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }
    });


  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes realizarlo dentro de `onItemClick()` con el valor de `position`, que es el indice del elemento seleccionado, en este ejemplo si das clic al elemento con "`position`" valor 2 se abriría una pagina web :

```
lista.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Pulsando el elemento no. " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if (position == 2){
            String url = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);
        }

    }
});
```